# JS/JQUERY: How to match and replace occurances inside specified strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I swear i tried figuring this out myself all day, but my regex-foo is just not that good.

I'm trying to create a small parser function to convert strings with urls to html coded  and  tags

I know how complex a regex can be trying to figure out which urls to covert to what from a big string, so what I did is simply prefix the string to covert with a flag to tell the parser how to format it, and post fix it with the ";" char to tell the parser where that particular URL ends. This way the parser has lesser guest work to do resulting in easier to regex-match and faster for execution. I really dont need a generalize match and replace all.

So my formatting is as follows, where "X" is the url string:

1. For URLs  it will be `url=X;`
2. For IMAGES it will be `img=X;`

so anything in between my prefix and post fix must be converted accordingly..

So for example, for images in my document, the string could be:

```
click this image img=http://example.com/image1.jpg;
```

and i need that converted to

```
click this image <a href="http://example.com/image1.jpg" target="_blank">
<img class="img img-responsive" src="http://example.com/image1.jpg"/></a>
```

I am able to do this easily in PHP buy preg_match() function

```
preg_match('/\img=(.+?)\;/i', $item_des, $matches)
```

here's the code block:
[image]

I decided to push this routine to the browser instead of the backend (PHP) so i need similar or better JS solution.

Hoping anyone can help here, thanks!

Comment: Why not use document.exec https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand .insertImage and contenteditable="true" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content and than you only get document.getElementById('yours_contenteditable_el').innerHTML

Comment: Could you show us your best attempt?

Answer (score 1):

try code below:

```js
var str = "click this image img=http://example.com/image1.jpg;image2 img=http://example.com/image2.jpg;"
var phrases = str.split(';');
var totalRes = '';
phrases.forEach(function(str){
  totalRes += processPhrase(str);
});
console.log(totalRes);
function processPhrase(str) {
  var img = str.split('img=')
  var res = '';
  if (img.length > 1) { //img=X
    var url = img[1].replace(';', '');
    res = img[0] + "<a href='" + url + "' target='_blank'><img src='" + url + "'/></a>";
  } else {
    var url = str.split('url=');
    //Do for url=X here
  }
  console.info(res);
  return res;
}
```

Comment: tnx for this, have not tried it yet, but i wanted to know if i had a rather large text block , will this be process heavy compared to regex matching??

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regexp `/(img|url)=(.+?);/g`:

```
(img|url) : the type, should be grouped so we will know what to do with the value
=         : literal "="
(.+?)     : a number of characters (use the non-greedy ? so it will match as fewer as possible)
;         : literal ";"
```

Read more about non-greedy regexps [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

---

**Example:**

```js
var str = "click this image img=http://i.imgur.com/3wY30O4.jpg?a=123&b=456; and check this URL url=http://google.com/;. Bye!";


// executer is an object that has functions that apply the changes for each type (you can modify the functions for your need)
var executer = {
  "url": function(e) {
    return '<a target="_blank" href="' + e + '">' + e + '</a>';
  },
  "img": function(e) {
    return '<a target="_blank" href="' + e + '"><img src="' + e + '"/></a>';
  }
}

var res = str.replace(/(img|url)=(.+?);/g, function(m, type, value) {
  return executer[type](value);    // executer[type] will be either executer.url or executer.img, then we pass the value to that function and return its returned value
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I think this must suppress `;` in result

Comment: so i tried this and it seems to work fine until it catches an ampersand sing "&" 

so if i have
http://i.imgur.com/3wY30O4.jpg?a=123&b=456;

and i want to put brackets around it, i get 

[http://i.imgur.com/3wY30O4.jpg?a=123&]b=456;

Works fine otherwise.
any ideas?

Comment: here's the snippet i used
http://i.imgur.com/PZ30HOw.jpg

See my previous explanation about the issue.

Comment: @BrownChiLD I bet it has something to do with encoding, you'e using `.html` to retrieve the content, then `&` will actually be `&amp;` (notice the `;` at the end). `console.log` the return value of `.html` to verify my assumption.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir spot on , that's what it was... so i added a replace routine 
var cur_des_html = cur_des_html.replace(/&amp;/g,"&");

and now it works awesome! thanks so much!